# Wrapping postback functions to call custom code at execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Here is my solution [for this stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326787/display-message-if-close-window-in-asp-net-but-not-on-postback)

It is designed to return an `onbeforeunload` message when the user leaves the page (excluding postbacks). It does this by logging a timestamp each time a .NET control causes a postback (either full or partial using update panels). When this happens, if `allowedWaitTime` has elapsed, amessage will be returned.

Are there any best or better practices missing from this code and does anyone have an opinion on my style (albeit a small sample)?

```
(function ($) {

    if (typeof $ !== 'function') {
        throw new Error('jQuery required');
    }

    /* The time in milliseconds to allow between a function call and 
       showing the onbeforeunload message. */
    var allowedWaitTime = 100,

        timeStamp = new Date().getTime(),

        // Each function to override
        baseFuncs = {
            __doPostBack: this.__doPostBack,
            WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions: this.WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions
        };

    // Set timeStamp when each baseFunc is called
    for (var baseFunc in baseFuncs) {
        (function (func) {
            this[func] = function () {
                var baseFunc = baseFuncs[func];
                timeStamp = new Date().getTime();
                if (typeof baseFunc === 'function') {
                    baseFunc.apply(arguments.callee, arguments);
                }
            }
        })(baseFunc);
    }

    /* Form submit buttons don't call __doPostBack so we'll set timeStamp 
       manually on click. */
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
        timeStamp = new Date().getTime();
    });

    $(this).on('beforeunload', function (e) {

        // Only return string if allowedWaitTime has elapsed
        if (e.timeStamp - timeStamp > allowedWaitTime) {
            return 'message';
        }
    });
}).call(window, jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question,

I think the biggest thing is that `callee` is [going the way of the Dodo bird](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee).

JsHint does not like your code because you are using `for( .. in .. )` without filtering properties, which is fine since you create the object with Object Notation, and I assume you did not modify the `Object` prototype. You are also creating functions/closures in a loop. Are you sure you need those closures there?

Other than well commented, and easy to follow, something that I would not mind using in one of my projects.